# Serverless AWS Lambda CORS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am trying to do an http request from an angularjs app to a lambda function that I had setup using serverless.

Here is my serverless.yaml function

```
functions:
   createcustomer:
    handler: handler.createcustomer
    events: 
      - http: post /createcustomer
        cors: true
```

Create Customer Function

```
module.exports.createcustomer = (event, context, callback) => {

    let customer = JSON.parse(event.body).customer;

    service.create(customer, function(result) {
        let response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                result: 'Created Customer Successfully',
                message: 'The account has been created!',
                type: 'success',
                customer: result
            })
        };
        callback(null, response);
    });
};
```

From my AngularJS app I call it like this

```
app.factory('MyFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        CreateCustomer: function(customer) {$http.post('<apipath>/createcustomer', {customer:customer})}
    }
}]);
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have tried to enable CORS in the API Gateway on the POST method, but that did not change the outcome.

I've also tried setting CORS in the yaml file explicitly

```
functions:
   createcustomer:
    handler: handler.createcustomer
    events: 
      - http: post /createcustomer
        cors:
          origin: '*'
```

Still no luck.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

One weird thing is that I could get the post to work just fine through PostMan, but if I try it through my app it breaks.

Thanks

UPDATE

[image]

When I do `serverless deploy` it shows up in AWS like the picture above and the method looks like this

[image]

As I said before, I tried to enable CORS directly from the API Gateway console but there was no difference when I tried to call the method.

Comment: Try by adding Access-Control-Allow-Headers header into lambda response.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare tried it, still no luck.

Comment: Looks right based on what you posted. I would check API Gateway console and Lambda console to check if those settings are really reflected and deployed properly.

Comment: I can get the response if I set the Content-Type to text/plain in my http request in Angular, but with application/json it fails.

Comment: something to do with sending a preflight option check, but when I set option on the api path it still fails when sending application/json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your update with screenshots shows that the OPTIONS method is not set up for any of these resources.  When you enable CORS for an API Gateway resource in the console, AWS sets this up automatically.

You can see this happen in the AWS console when you enable CORS for a resource, but, of course, your `serverless deploy` is overwriting this configuration.

To have the `/createcustomer` resource properly configured in AWS by the serverless deploy, you can rewrite this part of your serverless.yaml:

```
events: 
  - http: post /createcustomer
    cors: true
```

To look like this:

```
events:
  - http:
      path: /createcustomer
      method: post
      cors: true
```

I'm not an expert in the framework's .yml syntax, so I can't explain exactly why this is.

Nonetheless, I've confirmed that a file like this:

```
functions:
  deletecustomer:
    handler: handler.deletecustomer
    events:
      - http:
          path: /deletecustomer
          method: post
          cors: true
  createcustomer:
    handler: handler.createcustomer
    events: 
      - http: post /createcustomer
        cors: true
```

will create two resources in AWS API Gateway, one correctly configured for CORS, and one missing the OPTIONS method:

[image: Two resources, one correct and one missing OPTIONS]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the configuration that could help. Please note that it's always safe to be specific in allowing the CORS origins. So better to lock the origin down to localhost:{port-number}. In addition, you can also enable credentials on CORS settings. Please see the following serverless config as an example:

```html
cors:
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
  headers:
    - Content-Type
    - X-Amz-Date
    - Authorization
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - X-Amz-User-Agent
  allowCredentials: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but haven't split into different lambda functions yet (everything is under one function)

After going round in many circles, I realised I was missing something when looking at the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#cors-setup), and I can allow this in one go instead of for every endpoint

Adding the following did the trick:

```
provider:
  httpApi:
    cors: true
```

I kept adding this to `function` but it actually needed to be in `provider`

Answer (score 0):

The cors configuration got moved up into the provider config:

provider:
httpApi:
cors: true

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two steps needed to be carried out.

1. Firstly, you need to configure `cors: true` either in your individual functions or at the top level provider, like this:

```
    
functions:
  getProduct:
    handler: handler.getProduct
    events:
      - http:
          path: product/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true # <-- CORS!
  createProduct:
    handler: handler.createProduct
    events:
      - http:
          path: product
          method: post
          cors: true # <-- CORS!
```

This bit ONLY handles the Pre-Fetch (OPTIONS) request. There's still the main request (GET / POST etc) to be handled

2. To handle the main request, you need to pass the access control allow origin headers in your response, like this:

```
    
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       ... // your data
    }),
  };
 
  callback(null, response);
```

Only when both are carried out, will the issue get resolved.

[Reference](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide)